# Getting empty list from database and async task

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, arraylist, android-sqlite

I have a contact table helper where I have method of getAllContacts from database. 
I am calling this method in an async task and returning an array list of contacts.

But as I did debug I found that conList from getAllContacts method returns 0.

```
 public ArrayList<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    ArrayList<Contact> conList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + CONTACT_TABLE;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            Contact contact = new Contact();

            contact.setContactId(cursor.getString(0));
            contact.setmUserName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setmPass(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setmMobileNo(cursor.getString(3));
            contact.setmEmailId(cursor.getString(4));
            contact.setmProfileImage(cursor.getString(5));
            contact.setmFullName(cursor.getString(6));
            contact.setmJobTitle(cursor.getString(7));
            contact.setmWorkAddress(cursor.getString(8));
            contact.setmWorkPhone(cursor.getString(9));
            contact.setmHomeAddress(cursor.getString(10));
            contact.setmCompany(cursor.getString(11));


            conList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return conList;
}
```

Async Task :

```
    public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<Contact>> {

        private Context mContext;
        private ContactTableHelper dbConnector;
        private GetContactsFromDbCallback getContactsFromDbCallback;

        public GetContacts(Context context,GetContactsFromDbCallback getContactsFromDbCallback)
        {

            this.mContext = context;
            this.getContactsFromDbCallback = getContactsFromDbCallback;
            dbConnector = new ContactTableHelper(context);

        }
    public interface GetContactsFromDbCallback{
        void doPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> contacts,boolean b);
    }

        @Override
        public ArrayList<Contact> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

            contacts = dbConnector.getAllContacts();

            return contacts;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> b) {
            if (b != null) {
                // set the adapter's Cursor

                getContactsFromDbCallback.doPostExecute(b,true);

                dbConnector.close();
            }
        }
}
```

Callback :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GetContacts.GetContactsFromDbCallback {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

}


@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    contactList.clear();

    if(!firstTimeLogin)
    {
        contactList.clear();

    //    contactDb = new ContactTableHelper(MainActivity.this);
    //    mDb = new UserTableHelper(MainActivity.this);

      // contactList = mDb.getAllContacts();

        new GetUser(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this).execute(mUserId);

        new GetContacts(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this).execute();

    }
    else {
        new GetUserAsyncTask(mUserId).execute(mUserId);
        new GetContactsAsyncTask(this, MainActivity.this, mUserId,MainActivity.this).execute();

        firstTimeLogin = false;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("UserProfile",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("login",firstTimeLogin);
        editor.commit();
    }

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    adapter = new ContactAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(MainActivity.this, recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            final Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

            // custom dialog

        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

}

@Override
public void doPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> contactArrayList,boolean y) {

   contactList = contactArrayList;

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

What's going wrong here? Please help.. Thank you..

Comment: Your database is empty?

Comment: By the way, you don't need a writable database for just a select statement

Comment: no database isn't empty,  before this I was calling this method in an activity   so it was working fine, @cricket_007

Comment: So, when you say "as I did debug", that was not from the Activity code, when it was working?

Comment: Also, why can't you just `return dbConnector.getAllContacts();`?

Comment: No did debug with async task code, from activity it was working well, yes I can return directly but the problem is I am not getting list from getAllContacts method. @cricket_007

Comment: I do not think the problem is the AsyncTask code. That looks absolutely fine. Please show how the callback is implemented and how you notified the adapter of changes within the Activity

Comment: What is the difference between `GetContacts` and `GetContactsAsyncTask`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this

```
contactList = contactArrayList;
```

You need to do this

```
contactList.clear();
contactList.addAll(contactArrayList);
```

---

You are de-referencing the arraylist, so the adapter no longer knows about the list that you are trying to notify it with.